# como hacer para que las preguntas repetidas vuelvan a la cola una y otra vez?

Tags: javascript

El código es una simulación del juego de pasapalabra, todo funciona bastante bien, o al menos lo que me pide el ejercicio que debo hacer, el problema lo tengo en las preguntas saltadas con la palabra pasapalabra, una vez echa toda la ronda de preguntas, las preguntas en las que se a introducido pasapalabra vuelven a aparecer, hasta ahí bien, lo que quiero es que en esas palabras si vuelvo a introducir pasapalabra vuelvan a la cola, el problema con el do while es que la palabra no se pone a la cola, sale de nuevo hasta que la responda o la falle.

```javascript
let questions = [
    { letter: "a", answer: "abducir", status: 0, question: "CON LA A. Dicho de una supuesta criatura extraterrestre: Apoderarse de alguien" },

    { letter: "b", answer: "bingo", status: 0, question: "CON LA B. Juego que ha sacado de quicio a todos los 'Skylabers' en las sesiones de precurso" },

    { letter: "c", answer: "churumbel", status: 0, question: "CON LA C. Niño, crío, bebé" },

    { letter: "d", answer: "diarrea", status: 0, question: "CON LA D. Anormalidad en la función del aparato digestivo caracterizada por frecuentes evacuaciones y su consistencia líquida" },
//...
];
```

```javascript
let preg;
let pregp;
let acertadas = 0;
let falladas = 0;
  
let pregunta = () => {
                for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
                    preg = prompt('Responda: ' + questions[i].question);
                    do {
                        if (preg === '') {
                            window.alert('Introduzca la palabra o pasapalabra para saltar a la siguiente definicion');
                            preg = prompt('Responda: ' + questions[i].question);
                        }
                    } while (preg === '');
            
                    if (preg === questions[i].answer) {
                        acertadas++;
                        questions[i].status = 1;
                        window.alert('Ha hacertado la pregunta');
                        questions[i].question;
            
                    } else if (preg === 'pasapalabra') {
                        questions[i].status = 0;
                        window.alert('pregunta para la siguiente ronda');  
            
                    } else if (preg === 'end') {
                        window.alert('No ha terminado la ronda y no entrara en el rankin');
                        console.log('Ha hacertado: ' + acertadas + ' palabras');
                        console.log('Ha fallado: ' + falladas + ' palabras');
                        pregunta();
            
                    } else {
                        falladas++;
                        questions[i].status = 2;
                        window.alert('Respuesta incorrecta, la palabra que buscabamos era: ' + questions[i].answer);
            
                    }
                } 
            };
≤
pregunta();
            
let pasaPalabra = () => {
                for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
                        do {
                            if (questions[i].status === 0) {
                                pregp = prompt('Responda preguntas saltadas: ' + questions[i].question);
            
                                if (pregp === 'pasapalabra') {
                                    questions[i].status = 0;
                                    window.alert('pregunta para la siguiente ronda');
                                
                                } else if (pregp === questions[i].answer) {
                                    acertadas++;
                                    questions[i].status = 1;
                                    window.alert('Ha hacertado la pregunta');
            
                                } else {
                                    falladas++;
                                    questions[i].status = 2;
                                    window.alert('Respuesta incorrecta, la palabra que buscabamos era: ' + questions[i].answer);
                                }
            
                            }
                             } while (questions[i].status === 0);
                        }
                    
                
                console.log('Ha hacertado: ' + acertadas + ' palabras');
                console.log('Ha fallado: ' + falladas + ' palabras');
            }

pasaPalabra();
```

Comment: Después de cambiar el estado, simplemente "brinca" esa iteración del ciclo con [continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)

Comment: a que te refieres con cambiar el estado? e estado probando cosas con continué pero no doy con el resultado correcto.